# Error qmake running

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019

Скомпилил из исходников qt, установил плагин в vs2019, начал компилировать проект, ничего не получилось, ошибка: Error running qmake

Два дня сидел, ничего не нагуглил.
Help

Comment: Путь до qmake указал

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ERROR running qmake qmake:(C:/Qt/bin/qmake) qmake:(C:/qtproj/qtproj/x64/Debug/qmake/temp) qmake: Error creating .vcxproj file

Comment: Проект находится по пути без пробелов и русских символов?

Comment: Пробелов и русских символов в путях нет